# mysqldump (Errcode: 2) trying do backup from java in linux (server) with wildfly

Tags: java, linux, backup, mysql, wildfly-9

I'm working in a linux-server with wilfly.

when java is train to execute the command:

```
String command = "mysqldump -h "+ hostDB +" -u "+ dbUsername +" "+ dbPassword +" "+ nameDB +" -r \""+ path + backUpFile+"\"";
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

it's returning `mysqldump: Can't create/write to file '"/usr/share/wildfly/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/data/dbBackup/20160301_151254.sql"' (Errcode: 2)`

but when I execute the line in the linux-server shell is working fine.

```
mysqldump -h xx.xx.xx.xx -u username"-pxxx" database -r "/usr/share/wildfly/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/data/dbBackup/20160301_151254.sql"
```

the host is in different machine.

the same code is working in my local machine in windows.

Comment: When you run the command in the shell are you using the same user as the one running the java process?

Comment: how I can check what user is using for java?

Comment: ps aux - will show all processes running on the machine and the user. You will have to find there

Comment: java is using the same user than when I run in the shell (root user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

in linux server works different that windows,

we need use

```
//for linux server          
String[] cmdarray = {"/bin/sh","-c",command};
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!. You save my day. I had the same erro on CentOS and Tomcat 8.